# Backup Exchange emails to file

Tags: backup, exchange

I'll be leaving my university soon and my Exchange email account will be discontinued. As I have a lot of important emails in there, I need to create a backup. I do not have another Exchange account where I can simply copy the emails (size is the problem, we're talking approx 100GB here), so I need to back them up on a thumbdrive.

My questions are:

1. How to create such a backup?
2. How to access the files from such a backup later, given that I don't have an Exchange server/account

PS: I'm on Mac with Outlook if that's relevant

Comment: Archive the email to a PST file and save that

Comment: And how would I search through these emails without importing them again to an Exchange server?

Comment: You can open a PST file in Outlook, so you do not necessarily need Exchange for that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ,there is no way to backup Exchange mails directly without Outlook. In your mention ,you do not want to set up Outlook.

Acknowledging the query, I would like to tell you that using Outlook Web app (OWA) is also not possible, the owa is purely meant for sending and receiving emails. It does not have a backup or export feature.

So I would still suggest you to use Outlook Client to backup the emails. About how to backup the emails by Outlook ,you can info this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-email-e5845b0b-1aeb-424f-924c-aa1c33b18833#:%7E:text=%20Back%20up%20your%20email%20%20%201,your%20files%2C%20enter%20and%20confirm%20a%20See%20More) If you don't want to use Outlook, I am afraid you would choose some third-party software for help.